# get_theme_mod() only working when the customizer is open

Tags: theme-customizer, get-theme-mod

I'm using the Customizer API to enable/disable different sections of a website.

When I have the customizer window open it seems that `get_theme_mod()` is returning a value ok. However as soon as I **save** and **close** the customizer window, `get_theme_mod()` does not return anything.

I've seen some other questions about using `type="option"` and `get_option()` but I want to see if I can get this to work.

My settings look like this:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'my_banner_setting', array(
    'default'           => '1',
    'sanitize_callback' => 'my_sanitize_checkbox',
) );
```

And then I get them like this:

```
if ( get_theme_mod( 'my_banner_setting' ) == 1 ) {

    get_template_part( 'sections/banner' );

}
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I was able to fix it by adding a default value at the end of `get_theme_mod()`

```
if (  get_theme_mod('my_banner_setting', 1) == 1 ) {

    // proceed

}
```

Not sure if there's another solution but this fixed it.

**update**

Looks like it was actually because my "1" was in quotes, removing the quote worked and I didn't have to declare the default in `get_theme_mod()` again.

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'my_banner_setting', array(
    'default'           => 1,
    'sanitize_callback' => 'my_sanitize_checkbox',
) );
```